# How to delete failed jobs en masse in Camunda Cockpit?

Tags: batch-file, jobs, camunda

I have a Camunda flow that has failed about 30k times, because the service it was hitting was shut down.  Is there a method for removing all of the failed jobs at once from inside the project cockpit?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems a few years ago and created a commandline application for accessing the rest api of the cockpit. It is available at https://github.com/jhorstmann/camunda-cockpit-client, an example usage would be

```
cockpit-client.py -u username -p password --all -e live -m "error message" --cancel
```

Where `live` referes to a section in a `cockit-client.yaml` configuration file, as described in the readme.

I no longer maintain that code, but maybe it solves your problem. If you use the enterprise version of camunda cockpit you could probably do the same with its built-in batch operations: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.11/webapps/cockpit/batch/batch-operation/.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a means to do this via the cockpit but since each instance of Camunda uses a different schema, I was able to drop and rebuild the schema to remove all of the failed jobs.